# Changing content of a component with each swipe of Swiper Library

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-state-management

I am new to React Native and am not completely familiar with state management. Currently I am using react-native-swiper library to hold my swipable images. Each swipe takes me to the next image. Code below

Fish.js:

```
<Swiper style={styles.wrapper} height={10} horizontal={true} >
      <View style={styles.slide1}>
        <Image
          resizeMode="stretch"
          style={styles.image}
          source={require('../resource/images/AzureDamsel.png')}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.slide2}>
        <Image
          resizeMode="stretch"
          style={styles.image}
          source={require('../resource/images/BicolourAngelfish.png')}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.slide3}>
        <Image
          resizeMode="stretch"
          style={styles.image}
          source={require('../resource/images/ClownTriggerfish.png')}
        />
      </View>
 </Swiper>
```

And I am importing this in my App.js where I have some Text component below this like so:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <ImageBackground
    style={globalStyles.backgroundImage}
    source={require('./resource/images/bg1080.jpeg')}
  >
  <Fish />
  <Text> Fish 1</Text>
  <Text> Fish 2</Text>
  </ImageBackground>
</View>
```

But I want the respective Text to show with each swipe. Example at image 1 the Text says Fish 1, then when I swipe the image and go to the second slide, the Text changes to Fish 2 and so on. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the snack provided by you and the issue is in the Fish.js file.
Replace **onIndexChange** with **onIndexChanged**. The updated code:

```
const Fish = ({ onIndexChanged }) => (
  <Swiper onIndexChanged={onIndexChanged}>
    // Rest of your code.
  </Swiper>
)
```

Link to updated snack : https://snack.expo.dev/BToSGo1z6

Comment: Hey it worked, thanks but what if I wanted to instead of changing just the index, add a Text like Fish Azure, Fish Salmon, etc.

Comment: Then you can create a mapping like so:

const fishMapping = ["Fish Azure", "Fish Salmon", "Fish Another"]

And then display `${fishMapping[activeIndex]}`

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain the active slide index in state and then render that index.

Inside of `App.js`

```js
const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState();

const onIndexChanged = (index) => setActiveIndex(index);

return (
  <View>
    <Fish
      onIndexChanged={onIndexChanged}
    />
    { activeIndex && <Text>`Fish ${activeIndex}`</Text> }
  </View>
)
```

Inside of `Fish.js` you need to pass the `onIndexChanged` prop into `Swiper`.

```js
const Fish = ({ onIndexChanged }) => (
  <Swiper onIndexChange={onIndexChanged}>
    // Rest of your code.
  </Swiper>
)
```

---

Checking your Snack, I can see some output but as you mentioned it's not what you are expecting.

Start the `activeIndex` state variable to 0.

```js
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
```

Pass `setActiveIndex` straight into `Fish` via the `onIndexChanged` prop. Now you will be able to remove the unnecessary `onIndexChanged` function from App.js

```js
<Fish onIndexChanged={setActiveIndex} />
```

Change your string interpolation to just render the text from fishMapping. Because `activeIndex` is no longer undefined, you do not need the additional check (`activeIndex &&`)

```js
<Text>{fishMapping[activeIndex]}</Text>
```

[Here's](https://snack.expo.dev/@hannigan/paranoid-carrot) an updated version of your Snack.

Comment: I tried this but didn't get any output. I have a sandbox for reference: https://snack.expo.dev/@jay_m/paranoid-carrot if you could please check it out